# Are there any known issues between ColdFusion 11 and Microsoft SQL Server 2017?

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

We are currently using ColdFusion 11 and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3).  The EOL for SQL Server 2008 R2 is on July 9th of this year, so we need to upgrade.  I figured we should just go ahead and upgrade to SQL Server 2017, since it's the most recent.  But, of course, we don't want to break ColdFusion 11 in the process.

Is anyone aware of any specific compatibility issues between ColdFusion 11 and SQL Server 2017?  I can find nothing on Google about it, and nothing here either.  But just to cover all the bases, I figured I'd go ahead and ask if anyone has run into any issues.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably more of a question for CF support, but there's this which states support for SQL Server 2017 in CF 2018: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/products/coldfusion/pdfs/cf2016/ColdFusion_Support_Matrix.pdf

Comment: I haven't read of any. Haven't seen SQL 2017 in the wild, however, by now. If you get problems with the built in connector you can switch to Microsoft's JDBC driver: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57782 Take the right version that complies to your JAVA version. Remember, ColdFusion 11 is EOL shortly, too.

Comment: ColdFusion 11 is also reaching End of Life as of April 2019. It is highly recommended to upgrade to ColdFusion 2018. https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2019/02/coldfusion-11-core-support-ends-april-2019/

Comment: I have never ran into any issues. And I run run some very strange variations. I currently run CF 2018 with `Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU10) (KB4342123) - 14.0.3037.1 (X64)  Jul 27 2018 09:40:27  Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS)` on MacOS.

Comment: WilGeno -- yes, the mainstream support for ColdFusion 11 ends in April of this year, but extended support goes until April of 2021.  So we've got a couple years until we absolutely must upgrade.  Our plan is to switch from ColdFusion to NodeJS by then.

Comment: @LaurenceMacNeill I think you may misunderstand the difference between Core and Extended Support for CF. With Extended, you'll get the major patches, but it doesn't include Security patches or Hotfixes. https://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2018/12/20/CF11_countdown_clock_is_ticking To me, I'd be more concerned over upgrading from CF11 to 2016/18 than I would be SQL 2008 to 2017. Both need to be done, but an App server is probably much more vulnerable than a database is.

Comment: Besides, not to be a naysayer here, but I've heard more than once that "We'll upgrade our CF code to X in the next couple of years." only to see that becoming a much bigger project than expected. NodeJS is a good choice, and if you were going from CF8, I'd say it would probably be worth a language change since there were so many changes since CF8. But from 11 would be a tough call. There were some good changes to CF since then, but not enough to require a full rewrite.